# Compile custom version of extjs

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd

Maybe someone can help me with my requirement.

I am in trouble about the compilation of a new custom version of extjs with the use of sencha CMD.
For this purpose, I have used diffetent instructions but with the same result. No one instructions seems to work properly or perhaps there is something wrog in these instruction.

Below, the latest instruction that I have used for produce a custom version for extjs.

```
sencha -debug=false compile -classpath="ext-6.0.1\classic\classic\src,ext-6.0.1\packages\core\src,ext-6.0.1\classic\classic\overrides" exclude -namespace Ext.chart and concat -yui -out "test.js"
```

After the execution of this instruction, in test.js I have a custom version of Extjs. Or so it seems.
If I include this js into a webpage, with Firefox and firebug I can see this error of javascript: "Ext is undefined".

From this, I have some questions:

- First of all, is this the correct way to compile a new custom version?
- The classpath parameter is correct? There are other paths to include?
- In the instruction above, I have included the "exclude" parameter (for the namespace Ext.chart) but if I search in the output file I can found the related functions. It is the correct way to exclude something? Ext.chart is the namespace or is the class name?

Thanks in advance for any reply.

Lorenzo.